# sum 2 tag with using regex

Tags: c#, regex, string

how i can sum 2 tag AD="?????" below with using regex?

```
enter code here
```

BILL_SPEC AA="0000700602" AB="139703" AC="3" ***AD="48861894"*** AE="40577760" AF=""

BILL_SPEC AA="0000700602" AB="139703" AC="2" ***AD="11161440"*** AE="6008124" AF=""

Comment: i suppose the line of text are in text file? you have only 2 lines of text? and  the lines have always the same structure?

Comment: yes this is a text file , no more 2 lines ,maybe more 1000 lines ,yes structure is fix

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to format the lines of your text file more cleanly?  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks for tips.  Are the braces `{` and `}` actually present at the beginning and end of the file, and nowhere else?

Comment: this is just a text   and save into a txt format i want with regex tag AD read and save to a value and for next AD save to second value and in finnaly i get sum of first value with second value , can you help me and give a c# code?!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

an example of solution :

```
        var parts = allText.Split(' ');
        var ad = Array.FindAll(parts, s => s.StartsWith("AD="));//select all strings beginning by AD=
        var index_of_ad = parts.Select((b, i) => b.StartsWith("AD=") ? i : -1).Where(i => i != -1).ToArray();//trap all index of AD=
        long lastvalue = long.Parse(Regex.Match(ad[0], @"\d+").Value);// extract number and convert to long (int32 maybe not enough wide)
        for (int i = 1; i < ad.Length; i++)
        {
            var value = long.Parse(Regex.Match(ad[i], @"\d+").Value) + lastvalue;
            ad[i] = "AD=\"" + value.ToString() + "\"";
            lastvalue = value;
            parts[index_of_ad[i]] = ad[i];
        }
        //rebuild allText 
        allText = string.Join(" ", parts);
```

Comment: all my text save in value that name's alltext ,i must search into alltext ,and thanks for your code but dont work for me and have error when i change to alltext ,my program write with windowsForm

Comment: http://uupload.ir/files/zc79_untitled.jpg"

Comment: i misunderstand something, you replace the second value inside text by the sum of both tags?

Comment: have you end of line in your text? \n or \r\n or nothings of these?

Comment: when i found  AD tag ,i must add with prvious value AD tage and overwrite on AD tage value

Comment: ok in fact its cumulative sum.. you dont have answer to my second question about end of line

Comment: i have update the solution following your explanation..(not easy to understand what you want!!...)

Comment: thanks frenchy, you solve my problem ,it 's work...